# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.plotting._timeseries'

Tags: python

not very proficient yet in python and i'm trying to run :

```py
import pyfolio as pf
pf.create_full_tear_sheet(portfolio.mean(axis=1))
```

(reference in the end of: https://blog.quantinsti.com/xgboost-python/)

in Anaconda/Spyder but get the

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.plotting._timeseries'

checked that pyfolio is installed and googled the error but didn't come across any solutions.

Would really appreciate some help.
tx!

Comment: what version of pandas are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the `pandas.plotting._timeseries` module is only available for pandas versions before `0.25.x`.

You can see the `_timeseries` module is present in [`0.24.x`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/tree/0.24.x/pandas/plotting)
 and is removed in [`0.25.x`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/tree/0.25.x/pandas/plotting) (looks like the API changed to `pandas.plotting._matplotlib.timeseries`).

If you install an older version of pandas (anything before 0.25.x), it should work. Here's an example for last `0.24.x` release:

```
pip install pandas==0.24.2
```

Comment: I'm glad it could help, please accept this answer so that other people can find it if they raise a similar question in the future. @pvp

Comment: i am new in SO (first posted question) but I believe its the tick turning green, right ? also clicked the up button. tx!!